# Forcing use of SSL connections in web dependent applications

Tags: macos, security, ssl

Many websites allow it, to use an SSL connection. But how can I force my web dependent applications (Safari e.g.) to establish such a more secure (I know, that SSL is not the solution for all security related problems) connection, and to fallback if it isn't possible?

Comment: If you are looking at a coding solution, this would be off-topic here. But there are also browser extensions etc. to force SSL if possible so any answer in that direction is highly welcome.

Answer (score 3):

A preliminary before getting to a solution: I think you would be unhappy with a solution which tried https with **every** site.  For sites which do not respond to https there would an unacceptable delay waiting for some timeout period before trying again with http.

My solution for you is [GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org).  This a proxy server running on your Mac.  As a result all web applications connect via GlimmerBlocker.  Though frequently used as an ad blocker, it has much more functionality including rewriting web requests or returning a redirect to your browser.

Here is a description of the [Request and Response Flow](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/Flow) inside GlimmerBlocker including how URLs can be modified.  Pretty sparse description, but can you started.

The first post in this [blog](http://rcbth.com) has a more detailed recipe for converting http requests to https.  This can be applied to specific web sites which you know do support https as well as http.

Using GlimmerBlocker beyond what is out of the box is not for the fainthearted, but it has the power to do almost everything conceivable to web requests.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [the HTTPS Everywhere project](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) from EFF.

> HTTPS Everywhere is a Firefox and Chrome extension that encrypts your
>   communications with many major websites, making your browsing more
>   secure.

There does not appear to be any support for Safari.

Comment: I know that project, but I want to integrate it deeper in the OS. Maybe with an universal proxy, which rewrites the URLs, that are being used?

Comment: What do you mean deeper in the OS, browsers do this at a low level

Comment: I think the OP means intercepting all http requests - not just those in a specific browser.  So a proxy server solution.